# Android Kotlin Room Inheritance when saving and Polymorphism when querying

Tags: android, kotlin, inheritance, polymorphism, android-room

I am working on an app where a user can send or receive messages. I have many entities that I am implementing using `Room`.
The issue I have is about how to correctly represent the data in a relationship database. I am trying to play with inheritance and polymorphism but I am blocked now.

Here is my `Message` entity

```
@Entity(tableName = "messages")
open abstract class Message (

    @PrimaryKey
    @SerializedName("id")
    open val id: String,

    @SerializedName("from")
    open val from: String, // User,

    @SerializedName("to")
    open val to: String? = null,

    @SerializedName("timestamp")
    open val timestamp: String,

    @SerializedName("type")
    open val type: String,
)  {
    abstract fun summary(): String
}
```

A `Message` can be a text message, so I have this `MessageText` entity

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "messages_texts",
    ignoredColumns = ["from", "to", "timestamp", "type"],
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Message::class,
            parentColumns = ["id"],
            childColumns = ["id"],
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        )
    ]
)
data class MessageText(
    override val id: String,
    override val from: String,
    override val to: String?,
    override val timestamp: String,
    override val type: String,

    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "text_id")
    @SerializedName("text_id", alternate = ["id", "textid", "textId"])
    val textId: String,

    @SerializedName("body")
    val body: String
) : Message (id, from, to, timestamp, type) {
    override fun summary(): String {
        return body;
    }
}
```

A `Message` can also be an image or audio message. So I have those two entities `MessageImage` and `MessageAudio`

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "messages_images",
    ignoredColumns = ["id", "from", "to", "timestamp", "type"]
)
data class MessageImage (
    override val id: String,
    override val from: String,
    override val to: String?,
    override val timestamp: String,
    override val type: String,

    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "image_id")
    @SerializedName("id")
    val imageId: String,
    @SerializedName("caption")
    val caption   : String?,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "image_mime_type")
    @SerializedName("mime_type")
    val mimeType  : String?,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "image_sha_256")
    @SerializedName("sha256")
    val sha256    : String?,
) : Message (id, from, to, timestamp, type) {
    override fun summary(): String {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
}

@Entity(
    tableName = "messages_audios",
    ignoredColumns = ["id", "from", "to", "timestamp", "type"]
)
data class MessageAudio (
    override val id: String,
    override val from: String,
    override val to: String?,
    override val timestamp: String,
    override val type: String,

    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "audio_id")
    @SerializedName("id")
    val audioId: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "audio_mime_type")
    @SerializedName("mime_type")
    val mimeType  : String?,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "audio_sha_256")
    @SerializedName("sha256")
    val sha256    : String?,
    @SerializedName("voice")
    val voice     : Boolean?
) : Message (id, from, to, timestamp, type) {
    override fun summary(): String {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
}
```

1. **The inheritance have been added recently. Before that there was only one class for handling text messages. Now with the inheritance, I don't know how to write the insert query so that it will split the data into the two table `Message` and `MessageText` or `MessageImage` or `MessageAudio`**. Any solution, please?

A `Message` is sent to and received by a `User`. Here is how is implemented in my code

```
@Entity(tableName = "users")
data class User(
    @SerializedName("name")
    val name: String,

    @PrimaryKey
    @SerializedName("phone_number", alternate = ["phoneNumber"])
    @ColumnInfo(name = "phone_number")
    val phoneNumber: String,

    @SerializedName("type")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "type")
    val type: String
)

data class UserWithSentMessages(
    @Embedded val user: User,

    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "phone_number",
        entityColumn = "from"
    )
    val messages: List<Message>
)

data class UserWithReceivedMessages(
    @Embedded val user: User,

    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "phone_number",
        entityColumn = "to"
    )
    val messages: List<Message>
)
```

To get the list of all the messages related to an user, I use this set of queries

```
@Dao
interface IUserDao {
    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM users")
    fun getUserWithSentMessages(): Flow<List<UserWithSentMessages>>

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM users")
    fun getUserWithReceivedMessages(): Flow<List<UserWithReceivedMessages>>
}

class UserDao(private val userDao: IUserDao) {
    fun getMessagesAboutUser(): Flow<List<MessagesAboutUser>> {
        val sentMessages = userDao.getUserWithSentMessages().map { it -> it.map { UserWithMessages(it.user, it.messages) } }
        val receivedMessages = userDao.getUserWithReceivedMessages().map { it -> it.map { UserWithMessages(it.user, it.messages) } }

        return sentMessages.zip(receivedMessages) { sent, received ->
            (sent + received)
                .groupBy ({ it.user }, { it.messages })
                .mapValues { (_, values) -> values.flatten() }
                .filterKeys { it.type == USER_TYPE_CUSTOMER }
                .map { (user, messages) ->
                    Log.d(TAG, "Map. User: $user. Messages: $messages")
                    MessagesAboutUser(
                        user,
                        messages.sortedBy { m -> m.iTimestamp },
                        messages.count { m -> m.state == "unread" }
                    )
                }
                .sortedBy { m -> m.lastMessage.iTimestamp }
        }
    }
}
```

2. **Do you think this is a good way to get all the messages from a user?**

The way I am fetching the list of messages from/to a user is only giving me data from the `Message` class.

2. **How to structure the different entities so that fetching the list of `Message` of a `User` will return a list having `MessageText`, `MessageAudio`, and `MessageImage`**?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You want POJO's, say ***MessageWithListOfAll3MessageTypes***  with the `Message` `@Embedded` and an `@Relation` for each of the message Types annotating a field that is a List of the respective type.

Then your `UserWith?????Messages` has and `@Relation` annotating a field that is a List of ***MessageWithListOfAll3MessageTypes***.

i.e. you approach it using a hierarchy of the POJO's.

Based loosely on your code consider the following POJO's:-

```
data class MessageWithListOfEachMessageType(
    @Embedded
    val message: Message,
    @Relation(
        entity = MessageText::class, parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "id"
    )
    val messageTextList: List<MessageText>,
    @Relation(
        entity = MessageImage::class, parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "id"
    )
    val messageImageList: List<MessageImage>
    /* .... */
)
```

- `....` = Audio omitted for brevity
- note that the id column, rather then being ignored is used as the parent column between a message type and the message.

And then instead of your `UserWith....` POJO:-

```
data class UserWithListOfSentMessagesWithListOfEachMessageType(
    @Embedded
    val user: User,
    @Relation(
        entity=Message::class, parentColumn = "phone_number", entityColumn = "from"
    )
    val sentMessagesWithWithListOfEachMessageType: List<MessageWithListOfEachMessageType>
)
```

Using a `@Dao` annotated interface:-

```
@Dao
interface AllDAOs {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(user: User): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(message: Message): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(messageText: MessageText): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(messageImage: MessageImage): Long

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM users")
    fun getUserWithSentMessagesAndRelatedMessageTypes(): List<UserWithListOfSentMessagesWithListOfEachMessageType>
}
```

and a suitable/usable `@Database` annotated class (note with `.allowMainThreadQueries` for brevity of the demo) and some activity code as per:-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: AllDAOs
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getAllDAOs()

        dao.insert(User("Fred","0000000000","1"))
        dao.insert(User("Mary","1111111111","2"))
        dao.insert(User("jane","2222222222","3"))

        dao.insert((Message("id01","0000000000","1111111111","2023-01-01 10:00:01","X")))
        dao.insert((Message("id02","1111111111","Fred","2023-01-01 10:05:01","Y")))
        dao.insert((Message("id03","0000000000","Jane","2023-02-02 10:00:00","Z")))

        dao.insert(MessageText("id01","0000000000","1111111111","2023-01-01 10:00:01","X","msg01","Hello"))
        dao.insert(MessageText("id01","0000000000","1111111111","2023-01-01 10:00:01","X","msg02","It is me"))
        dao.insert(MessageText("id01","0000000000","1111111111","2023-01-01 10:00:01","X","msg03","How are you"))

        dao.insert(MessageText("id02","1111111111","1111111111","2023-01-01 10:00:01","X","msg04","Hello"))
        dao.insert(MessageText("id02","1111111111","1111111111","2023-01-01 10:00:01","X","msg05","Who Are you"))
        dao.insert(MessageText("id02","1111111111","1111111111","2023-01-01 10:00:01","X","msg06","I am Good"))

        dao.insert(MessageImage("id01","Fred","Mary","....","X","msg07","Image001","X","A0A1A2"))

        for(uw in dao.getUserWithSentMessagesAndRelatedMessageTypes()) {
            val messageinfo = StringBuilder()
            for (mi in uw.sentMessagesWithWithListOfEachMessageType) {
                val imageinfo = StringBuilder()
                for (image in mi.messageImageList) {
                    imageinfo.append("\n\t\tImage is ${image.caption}")
                }
                val txtinfo = StringBuilder()
                for (txt in mi.messageTextList) {
                    txtinfo.append("\n\t\tText is ${txt.body}")
                }
                messageinfo.append("\n Message ID: ${mi.message.id} From: ${mi.message.from} To: ${mi.message.to} ...." +
                        "\nThe message has ${mi.messageTextList.size} MessageTexts; they are:-${txtinfo}" +
                        "\nThe Message has ${mi.messageImageList.size} Messages Images; they are ${imageinfo}")
            }
            Log.d("DBINFO","USER name: ${uw.user.name} Phone: ${uw.user.phoneNumber}. There are ${uw.sentMessagesWithWithListOfEachMessageType.size} messages. They are${messageinfo}")
        }
    }
}
```

- note phone number is only relevant for the User - Message relationship. As previously stated the Mess - Message Type relationship is via the id columns.

The code is designed to run just the once to demonstrate and doing so results in the log containing:-

```
2023-08-27 21:20:01.939 D/DBINFO: USER name: Fred Phone: 0000000000. There are 2 messages. They are
     Message ID: id01 From: 0000000000 To: 1111111111 ....
    The message has 3 MessageTexts; they are:-
            Text is Hello
            Text is It is me
            Text is How are you
    The Message has 1 Messages Images; they are 
            Image is Image001
     Message ID: id03 From: 0000000000 To: Jane ....
    The message has 0 MessageTexts; they are:-
    The Message has 0 Messages Images; they are 
2023-08-27 21:20:01.940 D/DBINFO: USER name: Mary Phone: 1111111111. There are 1 messages. They are
     Message ID: id02 From: 1111111111 To: Fred ....
    The message has 3 MessageTexts; they are:-
            Text is Hello
            Text is Who Are you
            Text is I am Good
    The Message has 0 Messages Images; they are 
2023-08-27 21:20:01.940 D/DBINFO: USER name: jane Phone: 2222222222. There are 0 messages. They are
```

---

---

*The rest of the code i.e. the entities used in the demo i.e. a cut down version of your entities* :-

```
@Entity(tableName = "messages")
data class Message (

    @PrimaryKey
    val id: String,
    val from: String, // User,
    val to: String? = null,
    val timestamp: String,
    val type: String,
)

@Entity(
    tableName = "messages_texts",
    //ignoredColumns = ["from", "to", "timestamp", "type"],
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Message::class,
            parentColumns = ["id"],
            childColumns = ["id"],
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        )
    ]
)
data class MessageText(
    val id: String,
    val from: String,
    val to: String?,
    val timestamp: String,
    val type: String,
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "text_id")
    val textId: String,
    val body: String
)
@Entity(
    tableName = "messages_images",
    //ignoredColumns = ["id", "from", "to", "timestamp", "type"]
)
data class MessageImage (
    val id: String,
    val from: String,
    val to: String?,
    val timestamp: String,
    val type: String,

    @PrimaryKey
    val imageId: String,
    val caption   : String?,
    val mimeType  : String?,
    val sha256    : String?,
)
@Entity(tableName = "users")
data class User(
    val name: String,

    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "phone_number")
    val phoneNumber: String,
    val type: String
)
```

- again **Note** that the Message Types are related to the parent Message via the Message's id column (primary key), the id field of the Type being used (un ignored) to store the parent's id.
- you could define them as a Foreign Key in the Image and Audio types  similar to how you have done for the Text type.

**PolyMorphism**

Extending the above with some crude Polymorphism and then the additional logging by the means of a single additional line for logging the **`summary`** as per:-

```
Log.d("SUMMARYINFO",uw.summary())
```

When all the relevant classes have a **`summary`** function as per:-

```
const val SUMMARY_DELIMINTAOR = "~!"
const val SUMMARY_NAME_START_DELIMINATOR = "{"
const val SUMMARY_NAME_END_DELIMINATOR ="}"
@Entity(tableName = "messages")
data class Message (

    @PrimaryKey
    val id: String,
    val from: String, // User,
    val to: String? = null,
    val timestamp: String,
    val type: String,
) {
    fun summary(): String {
        val sb = StringBuilder()
        sb.append(SUMMARY_NAME_START_DELIMINATOR).append("id=").append(SUMMARY_NAME_END_DELIMINATOR).append(id)
        sb.append(SUMMARY_DELIMINTAOR)
        sb.append(SUMMARY_NAME_START_DELIMINATOR).append("from=").append(SUMMARY_NAME_END_DELIMINATOR).append(from)
        sb.append(SUMMARY_DELIMINTAOR)
        sb.append(SUMMARY_NAME_START_DELIMINATOR).append("to=").append(SUMMARY_NAME_END_DELIMINATOR).append(to)
        sb.append(SUMMARY_DELIMINTAOR)
        sb.append(SUMMARY_NAME_START_DELIMINATOR).append("timestamp=").append(SUMMARY_NAME_END_DELIMINATOR).append(timestamp)
        sb.append(SUMMARY_DELIMINTAOR)
        sb.append(SUMMARY_NAME_START_DELIMINATOR).append("type=").append(SUMMARY_NAME_END_DELIMINATOR).append(type)
        return sb.toString()
    }
}

@Entity(
    tableName = "messages_texts",
    //ignoredColumns = ["from", "to", "timestamp", "type"],
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Message::class,
            parentColumns = ["id"],
            childColumns = ["id"],
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        )
    ]
)
data class MessageText(
    val id: String,
    val from: String,
    val to: String?,
    val timestamp: String,
    val type: String,
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "text_id")
    val textId: String,
    val body: String
) {
    fun summary(): String {
        val sb = StringBuilder()
        sb.append(SUMMARY_NAME_START_DELIMINATOR).append("textId=").append(SUMMARY_NAME_END_DELIMINATOR).append(textId)
        sb.append(SUMMARY_DELIMINTAOR)
        sb.append(SUMMARY_NAME_START_DELIMINATOR).append("id=").append(SUMMARY_NAME_END_DELIMINATOR).append(id)
        sb.append(SUMMARY_DELIMINTAOR)
        sb.append(SUMMARY_NAME_START_DELIMINATOR).append("from=").append(SUMMARY_NAME_END_DELIMINATOR).append(from)
        sb.append(SUMMARY_DELIMINTAOR)
        sb.append(SUMMARY_NAME_START_DELIMINATOR).append("to=").append(SUMMARY_NAME_END_DELIMINATOR).append(to)
        sb.append(SUMMARY_DELIMINTAOR)
        sb.append(SUMMARY_NAME_START_DELIMINATOR).append("timestamp=").append(SUMMARY_NAME_END_DELIMINATOR).append(timestamp)
        sb.append(SUMMARY_DELIMINTAOR)
        sb.append(SUMMARY_NAME_START_DELIMINATOR).append("body=").append(SUMMARY_NAME_END_DELIMINATOR).append(body)
        return sb.toString()
    }
}
@Entity(
    tableName = "messages_images",
    //ignoredColumns = ["id", "from", "to", "timestamp", "type"]
)
data class MessageImage (
    val id: String,
    val from: String,
    val to: String?,
    val timestamp: String,
    val type: String,

    @PrimaryKey
    val imageId: String,
    val caption   : String?,
    val mimeType  : String?,
    val sha256    : String?,
) {
    fun summary(): String {
        val sb = StringBuilder()
        sb.append(SUMMARY_NAME_START_DELIMINATOR).append("textId=").append(SUMMARY_NAME_END_DELIMINATOR).append(imageId)
        sb.append(SUMMARY_DELIMINTAOR)
        sb.append(SUMMARY_NAME_START_DELIMINATOR).append("id=").append(SUMMARY_NAME_END_DELIMINATOR).append(id)
        sb.append(SUMMARY_DELIMINTAOR)
        sb.append(SUMMARY_NAME_START_DELIMINATOR).append("from=").append(SUMMARY_NAME_END_DELIMINATOR).append(from)
        sb.append(SUMMARY_DELIMINTAOR)
        sb.append(SUMMARY_NAME_START_DELIMINATOR).append("to=").append(SUMMARY_NAME_END_DELIMINATOR).append(to)
        sb.append(SUMMARY_DELIMINTAOR)
        sb.append(SUMMARY_NAME_START_DELIMINATOR).append("timestamp=").append(SUMMARY_NAME_END_DELIMINATOR).append(timestamp)
        sb.append(SUMMARY_DELIMINTAOR)
        sb.append(SUMMARY_NAME_START_DELIMINATOR).append("caption=").append(SUMMARY_NAME_END_DELIMINATOR).append(caption)
        sb.append(SUMMARY_DELIMINTAOR)
        sb.append(SUMMARY_NAME_START_DELIMINATOR).append("mimeType=").append(SUMMARY_NAME_END_DELIMINATOR).append(mimeType)
        sb.append(SUMMARY_DELIMINTAOR)
        sb.append(SUMMARY_NAME_START_DELIMINATOR).append("sha256=").append(SUMMARY_NAME_END_DELIMINATOR).append(sha256)
        return sb.toString()
    }
}
@Entity(tableName = "users")
data class User(
    val name: String,

    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "phone_number")
    val phoneNumber: String,
    val type: String
) {
    fun summary(): String {
        val sb = StringBuilder()
        sb.append(SUMMARY_NAME_START_DELIMINATOR).append("phoneNumber=").append(SUMMARY_NAME_END_DELIMINATOR).append(phoneNumber)
        sb.append(SUMMARY_DELIMINTAOR)
        sb.append(SUMMARY_NAME_START_DELIMINATOR).append("name=").append(SUMMARY_NAME_END_DELIMINATOR).append(name)
        sb.append(SUMMARY_DELIMINTAOR)
        sb.append(SUMMARY_NAME_START_DELIMINATOR).append("type=").append(SUMMARY_NAME_END_DELIMINATOR).append(type)
        return sb.toString()
    }
}

data class MessageWithListOfEachMessageType(
    @Embedded
    val message: Message,
    @Relation(
        entity = MessageText::class, parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "id"
    )
    val messageTextList: List<MessageText>,
    @Relation(
        entity = MessageImage::class, parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "id"
    )
    val messageImageList: List<MessageImage>
    /* .... */
) {
    fun summary(): String {
        val sb = StringBuilder()
        sb.append(SUMMARY_NAME_START_DELIMINATOR).append("message=").append(SUMMARY_NAME_END_DELIMINATOR).append(message.summary())
        sb.append(SUMMARY_DELIMINTAOR)
        sb.append(SUMMARY_NAME_START_DELIMINATOR).append("messTextList=").append(SUMMARY_NAME_END_DELIMINATOR)
        for (mtl in messageTextList) {
            sb.append(SUMMARY_DELIMINTAOR)
            sb.append(mtl.summary())
        }
        sb.append(SUMMARY_NAME_START_DELIMINATOR).append("messageImageList=").append(SUMMARY_NAME_END_DELIMINATOR)
        for (mil in messageImageList) {
            sb.append(SUMMARY_DELIMINTAOR)
            sb.append(mil.summary())
        }
        return sb.toString()
    }
}
data class UserWithListOfSentMessagesWithListOfEachMessageType(
    @Embedded
    val user: User,
    @Relation(
        entity=Message::class, parentColumn = "phone_number", entityColumn = "from"
    )
    val sentMessagesWithListOfEachMessageType: List<MessageWithListOfEachMessageType>
) {
    fun summary(): String {
        val sb = StringBuilder()
        sb.append(SUMMARY_NAME_START_DELIMINATOR).append("user=").append(SUMMARY_NAME_END_DELIMINATOR).append(user.summary())
        sb.append(SUMMARY_NAME_START_DELIMINATOR).append("sentMessageWithListOfEachMessageType=").append(SUMMARY_NAME_END_DELIMINATOR)
        for (smwloemt in sentMessagesWithListOfEachMessageType) {
            sb.append(SUMMARY_DELIMINTAOR)
            sb.append(smwloemt.summary())
        }
        return sb.toString()
    }
}
```

That is with the loop retrieving all users with messages and with the messages list of each type (text and image) now being:-

```
    for(uw in dao.getUserWithSentMessagesAndRelatedMessageTypes()) {
        val messageinfo = StringBuilder()
        for (mi in uw.sentMessagesWithListOfEachMessageType) {
            val imageinfo = StringBuilder()
            for (image in mi.messageImageList) {
                imageinfo.append("\n\t\tImage is ${image.caption}")
            }
            val txtinfo = StringBuilder()
            for (txt in mi.messageTextList) {
                txtinfo.append("\n\t\tText is ${txt.body}")
            }
            messageinfo.append("\n Message ID: ${mi.message.id} From: ${mi.message.from} To: ${mi.message.to} ...." +
                    "\nThe message has ${mi.messageTextList.size} MessageTexts; they are:-${txtinfo}" +
                    "\nThe Message has ${mi.messageImageList.size} Messages Images; they are ${imageinfo}")
        }
        Log.d("DBINFO","USER name: ${uw.user.name} Phone: ${uw.user.phoneNumber}. There are ${uw.sentMessagesWithListOfEachMessageType.size} messages. They are${messageinfo}")
        Log.d("SUMMARYINFO",uw.summary())
    }
```

- i.e. the exact same data is added and just the single additional line `Log.d("SUMMARYINFO",uw.summary())` added to the loop; then the output to the log is

:-

```
2023-08-30 09:51:17.455 D/DBINFO: USER name: Fred Phone: 0000000000. There are 2 messages. They are
     Message ID: id01 From: 0000000000 To: 1111111111 ....
    The message has 3 MessageTexts; they are:-
            Text is Hello
            Text is It is me
            Text is How are you
    The Message has 1 Messages Images; they are 
            Image is Image001
     Message ID: id03 From: 0000000000 To: Jane ....
    The message has 0 MessageTexts; they are:-
    The Message has 0 Messages Images; they are 
2023-08-30 09:51:17.455 D/SUMMARYINFO: {user=}{phoneNumber=}0000000000~!{name=}Fred~!{type=}1{sentMessageWithListOfEachMessageType=}~!{message=}{id=}id01~!{from=}0000000000~!{to=}1111111111~!{timestamp=}2023-01-01 10:00:01~!{type=}X~!{messTextList=}~!{textId=}msg01~!{id=}id01~!{from=}0000000000~!{to=}1111111111~!{timestamp=}2023-01-01 10:00:01~!{body=}Hello~!{textId=}msg02~!{id=}id01~!{from=}0000000000~!{to=}1111111111~!{timestamp=}2023-01-01 10:00:01~!{body=}It is me~!{textId=}msg03~!{id=}id01~!{from=}0000000000~!{to=}1111111111~!{timestamp=}2023-01-01 10:00:01~!{body=}How are you{messageImageList=}~!{textId=}msg07~!{id=}id01~!{from=}Fred~!{to=}Mary~!{timestamp=}....~!{caption=}Image001~!{mimeType=}X~!{sha256=}A0A1A2~!{message=}{id=}id03~!{from=}0000000000~!{to=}Jane~!{timestamp=}2023-02-02 10:00:00~!{type=}Z~!{messTextList=}{messageImageList=}
2023-08-30 09:51:17.457 D/DBINFO: USER name: Mary Phone: 1111111111. There are 1 messages. They are
     Message ID: id02 From: 1111111111 To: Fred ....
    The message has 3 MessageTexts; they are:-
            Text is Hello
            Text is Who Are you
            Text is I am Good
    The Message has 0 Messages Images; they are 
2023-08-30 09:51:17.457 D/SUMMARYINFO: {user=}{phoneNumber=}1111111111~!{name=}Mary~!{type=}2{sentMessageWithListOfEachMessageType=}~!{message=}{id=}id02~!{from=}1111111111~!{to=}Fred~!{timestamp=}2023-01-01 10:05:01~!{type=}Y~!{messTextList=}~!{textId=}msg04~!{id=}id02~!{from=}1111111111~!{to=}1111111111~!{timestamp=}2023-01-01 10:00:01~!{body=}Hello~!{textId=}msg05~!{id=}id02~!{from=}1111111111~!{to=}1111111111~!{timestamp=}2023-01-01 10:00:01~!{body=}Who Are you~!{textId=}msg06~!{id=}id02~!{from=}1111111111~!{to=}1111111111~!{timestamp=}2023-01-01 10:00:01~!{body=}I am Good{messageImageList=}
2023-08-30 09:51:17.458 D/DBINFO: USER name: jane Phone: 2222222222. There are 0 messages. They are
2023-08-30 09:51:17.458 D/SUMMARYINFO: {user=}{phoneNumber=}2222222222~!{name=}jane~!{type=}3{sentMessageWithListOfEachMessageType=}
```

- i.e. the 3 Summaries, as per the **`summary`** function, are now included